# Gradle - Exclude package from Eclipse project buildpath

Tags: gradle

How would I exclude a package from the buildpath when building a project for Eclipse using Gradle?

Answer (score 0):

There are some examples described in the docs:
http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseClasspath.html

```
eclipse {

  //if you want parts of paths in resulting file to be replaced by variables (files):
  pathVariables 'GRADLE_HOME': file('/best/software/gradle'), 'TOMCAT_HOME': file('../tomcat')

  classpath {
    //you can tweak the classpath of the eclipse project by adding extra configurations:
    plusConfigurations += configurations.provided

    //you can also remove configurations from the classpath:
    minusConfigurations += configurations.someBoringConfig

    //if you don't want some classpath entries 'exported' in eclipse
    noExportConfigurations += configurations.provided

    //if you want to append extra containers:
    containers 'someFriendlyContainer', 'andYetAnotherContainer'

    //customizing the classes output directory:
    defaultOutputDir = file('build-eclipse')

    //default settings for dependencies sources/javadoc download:
    downloadSources = true
    downloadJavadoc = false
  }
}
```